# As of spaCy v3.0, model symlinks are not supported anymore

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, spacy, spacy-3

I need to convert FastText vectors to SpaCy for a non-English language, for which purpose I built and installed (pip) a custom .tar.gz model.
Now I want to link the package with SpaCy but the old command has been up to v3.0 deprecated.

I tried following steps:

```
 - pip install dist/cs_model-0.0.0.tar.gz
 - python -m spacy link cs_model cs
```

The error:

```
As of spaCy v3.0, model symlinks are not supported anymore. You can load trained pipeline packages using their full names or from a directory path.
```

The documentation says:

> not needed, symlinks are deprecated

I'm a bit confused how I'm supposed to link my language model with SpaCy...
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just need to use the name of the model directly, instead of using shortcut\synonyms, such as:

```
language: cs_model
```